# How to make ReSharper stop unwrapping my lambdas in cshtml?

Tags: resharper, word-wrap

I have the following code in a .cshtml file:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeFk)
      .DataSource(ds =>
      {
          ds.Read(r =>
          {
              r.Action(nameof(TaskController.GetTypes), "Task").Data("getTmNum");
          }).ServerFiltering(true);
      }))
```

When I run ReSharper's Cleanup Code function on the file, it changes it to:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeFk)
      .DataSource(ds => { ds.Read(r => { r.Action(nameof(TaskController.GetTypes), "Task").Data("getTmNum"); }).ServerFiltering(true); }))
```

I've tried to find the option to configure this under ReSharper | Options | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping. But I can't seem to find it.

How do I make this stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off an option called "Place simple anonymous method on single line".[image]